# script not running before sleep

Tags: bash, linux-mint, xrandr

I am trying to create a script that runs just before sleeping. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? This script runs perfectly when I run the command in terminal.

```
king@death-star /etc/pm/sleep.d $ ls
total 1MB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1MB May 30 15:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 1MB Nov 28  2015 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1MB Jun 26  2015 10_grub-common
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1MB Dec  6  2013 10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1MB May 22  2012 novatel_3g_suspend
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1MB May 30 15:20 revert_kb_on_sleep

king@death-star /etc/pm/sleep.d $ cat revert_kb_on_sleep 
sh -c "/home/king/Desktop/Scripts/rotate_desktop normal; /home/king/Desktop/Scripts/misc/my_keyboard on"
```

Output from log:

```
$ cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/revert_kb_on_sleep suspend suspend:
Can't open display 
Can't open display 
xrandr: --rotate requires an argument
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
No protocol specified
Unable to connect to X server
/etc/pm/sleep.d/revert_kb_on_sleep suspend suspend: success.

Mon May 30 15:23:39 EDT 2016: performing suspend
Mon May 30 15:27:59 EDT 2016: Awake.
Mon May 30 15:27:59 EDT 2016: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/revert_kb_on_sleep resume suspend:
Can't open display 
Can't open display 
xrandr: --rotate requires an argument
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
No protocol specified
Unable to connect to X server
/etc/pm/sleep.d/revert_kb_on_sleep resume suspend: Returned exit code 1.
```

Comment: It looks like the X-Windows context / DISPLAY environment variable is not set when run from the daemon - you could try adding something like `-d :0.0` (display option) to the xrandr, and then hope that you don't run into permission issues. I have the feeling that what you are trying to do does not belong into the sleep.d dir but maybe your window manager/desktop settings have a place where you can specify some actions ...?

Comment: Im fairly new to linux mint, I will do some research and comment back if I find anything. Thanks for the tip. For anyone reading this in the future the `-d :0.0` will cause permissions issues. I discovered this when initially getting the script to work.

Comment: No luck finding another way to do this....Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: find out what user is running the script,- either allow that user a sudo to your user and try the `-d :0.0` thing - or try `xhost +local` and try with or without sudo from the user that runs the sleep script - if you like it I would create an answer for my reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any luck with this? I wrote a script to run after waking, and I'm getting similar errors. This script is supposed to turn off the laptop display upon waking from sleep.

```
case "${1}" in
resume|thaw)
screen_status=$(xset -q -display :0.0 | tail -1 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//g')

if [[ "$screen_status" = "Monitor is On" ]]; then
    sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
fi
;;
esac
```

But I get the following error:

`No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0.0"`

I've tried to get it to set screen_status as "Monitor is off" when it can't get a display, so that it triggers the condition to execute xset anyway, but that's not working, either, because it can't access the display. In the meantime, I set xfce4-power-manager to turn off the screen after 1 minute. Having to wait for a minute is better than nothing!